# trying to get string from Pastebin not working (HWID) python

Tags: python, python-requests, pastebin, hwid

code below worked for some time now it completely doesnt work

no errors just not getting my hwid in that requests.get('PB URL').text:

```
import requests
import subprocess
hwid = subprocess.check_output('wmic csproduct get uuid').decode().split('\n')[1].strip()
if hwid not in requests.get('PB URL').text:
#code
```

Comment: Why does your title say "Pastebin"? Are you supposed to replace `requests.get('PB URL')` with the _actual_ Pastebin URL? Didn't you get an error about an invalid URL? What exactly doesn't work, the request to `PB URL` or the checking of `hwid`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.